# Angular 2 deploy to IIS sub folder - returns 404 for images in Assets

Tags: angular, iis, deployment, angular-cli, subdirectory

I'm using angular-cli ng build to build the angular 2 build package. Then I deploy all the files from "dist" to a sub-folder in the application root, "root/apps" in the IIS. The application loads the bundled .js files fine but the images in assets folder return 404. I've tried setting the base-href to "apps" and "/apps/" but the result is same. 
Using the dev tools I found that the application is looking for the images at root->assets. One option is that I copy Assets at the root level but it seems like a dirty-workaround. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: i would suggest you to chnage all the image paths to base path and then try it will work then ,

Comment: Thanks Rahul Singh. That worked.